# Getting the highest number from form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in html and I want to extract the highest number from the field using javascript. For example:

```
<input id="temp_0__Amount" name="temp[0].Amount" type="text" value="lorum ipsum">
<input id="temp_1__Amount" name="temp[1].Amount" type="text" value="lorum ipsum">
<input id="temp_2__Amount" name="temp[2].Amount" type="text" value="lorum ipsum">
```

In this case I want a javascript to produce 2.

I was trying something with jQuery but I cant get further then:

```
$('input[name^="temp"]').last().name;
```

This would produce `temp[2].Amount`. But I just want to extract 2. Not the whole sentence. And I know I could just use things like substring, but I wondered if there is a "clean" way.

Comment: In my opinion the "clean" way would be to add a `data-` attribute containing just the string your code needs.

Comment: @Pointy - had the exact same thought.

Comment: @Pointy sorry but this is not possible, those fields are generated by ASP.NET MVC. I want to retrieve the last number so I can add another input field with the next number.

Comment: Well I think ASP.NET MVC is fully capable of adding attributes to HTML elements, but whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $('input').map(function(){
      return this.name.match(/\d+/);
}).get());

console.log(max);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpw3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract just number 2:

```
$('input[name^="temp"]').size()-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data- attribute here:-

```
<input id="temp_0__Amount" name="temp[0].Amount" data-amount="0" type="text" value="lorum ipsum">
<input id="temp_1__Amount" name="temp[1].Amount" data-amount="1" type="text" value="lorum ipsum">
<input id="temp_2__Amount" name="temp[2].Amount" data-amount="2"  type="text" value="lorum ipsum">
```

you can get value in jquery :-

```
 var amount = $('input[name^="temp"]').last().data('amount');
```

See live demo here [Live demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/eL2ne/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Little fancy (one more solution):

```
var max = $('input').map(function(){
   return this.name.match(/\d+/);
}).get().sort().reverse()[0];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wSmEV/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var lastName = $('input[name^="temp"]').find(":last").prop("name"),
    amount = lastName.replace(/^temp\[|\]\.Amount/g,'');
```